# SQL append variable string to WHERE clause depending on condition

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

So I am trying to create a SQL statement and I have some conditions. Basically the user inputs (by a HTML form in JSP) semester and if it's graduate or undergraduate course, then a list of all courses in that criteria is shown.

What I have so far is this

```
SELECT course
FROM coursetable
WHERE semester = 'fall'
```

Now I want to add that if you type in graduate, then it will add

```
WHERE semester ='fall'
AND grad_level = graduate
```

but if you type in undergraduate, then it will add

```
WHERE semester ='fall'
AND grad_level = undergraduate
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do (if you're using JDBC) is set your SQL query to use parameters, like this:

```
String strSQL = "SELECT course FROM coursetable WHERE semester = ? AND grad_level = ?";
```

Then when you make the call from your Java code, you'll add "semester" and "gradLevel" as parameters.  Again, if you're using JDBC, it would look something like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(strSQL);
pstmt.setString(1, strSemester);
pstmt.setString(2, strGradLevel);
```

This is assuming that you've set strSemester and strGradLevel to the input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is just for practice as you really should separate your business logic from your view (ie jsp).
Please search [mvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Java) and choose a framework that fits you.
Also use a [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

To simply get the job done your sql should be

```
SELECT course FROM coursetable WHERE semester = ? AND grad_level = ?
```

and use the set your parameters on your prepared statement.

```
your_preparedStatement.setString(1, semester);
your_preparedStatement.setString(2, level);
```

If you need to dynamically add and remove columns its quickest to use a StringBuilder and append.
But there are frameworks for this such as [Squiggle](http://code.google.com/p/squiggle-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically alter your query using JSTL conditionals.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
. . .
<sql:query dataSource="jdbc/example" var="courses">
SELECT course FROM courseTable WHERE semester=?
<sql:param value="${semester}"/>
<c:if test="${not empty param.graduate}">
AND grad_level=?
<sql:param value="${param.graduate}"/>
</c:if>
</sql:query>
```